# Numpy accurately computing the inverse of a matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, math, matrix, eigenvalue

I am trying to compute the eigen values of a matrix built by a matrix product M^{-1}K.

I know M and K, I have initialized them properly. I thus try to compute the inverse of M:

```py
M_inv = np.linalg.inv(M)
with np.printoptions(threshold=np.inf, precision=10, suppress=True,linewidth=20000):
    print(np.matrix(M_inv * M))
```

That should print the identity, but I get:

[image]

Which clearly is not the identity. I need to find the eigen values of M_inv * K, but if M_Inv is so innacurate I won't get anything useful, what do I do?

This is the matrix:

[image]

And this is my initialization code:

```py
def mij(i, j, h):
    if i==j:
        return 2.0 * h / 3.0
    else:
        return h / 6.0

def kij(i, j, h):
    if i==j:
        return 2.0 / h
    else:
        return -1 / h

n = 500

size=n+1
h = 1 / n
t=np.linspace(0,1,n)
# Get A
M = np.zeros((n, n))
K = np.zeros((n, n))

for i in range(0, n):
    M[i,i] = mij(i, i, h)
    if i+1 < n:
        M[i,i+1] = mij(i, i+1, h)
    if i-1 >= 0:
        M[i,i-1] = mij(i, i-1, h)

    K[i,i] = kij(i, i, h)
    if i+1 < n:
        K[i,i+1] = kij(i, i+1, h)
    if i-1 >= 0:
        K[i,i-1] = kij(i, i-1, h)
```

Comment: What are the values of M? Are you sure M is invertible?

Comment: @Damien added both the theory formulation and the init code. And yes, M is tri-diagonal, so very much invertible

Comment: @cards I was hasty and posted the wrong code

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why are you taking an explicit inverse of M? That's not a typical way to implement `M^{-1}K` but perhaps there was some specific reason for it

Comment: @harold sheer ignorance on my end. How would I compute M_inv * K without taking the inverse?

Comment: @Makogan typically by factoring M into parts for which there are efficient ways to solve systems of linear equations (Cholesky, LU, QR, etc), then doing some triangular solves. M being tridiagonal enables Thomas' algorithm too.

Comment: That `*` is an elementwise product, not a matrix product. Calling `np.matrix` *after* computing the product doesn't change that (and you shouldn't use `np.matrix` anyway).

Comment: Try return -1.0 / h

Comment: Note that often for such simple matrices, there exists a closed-form solution. You can find the solution of your matrix (up to a multiplicative coefficient) on math.se, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088627/inverse-of-a-tridiagonal-matrix).

Answer (score 1):

Try to compute the inverse column by column using this:

```
c1 = numpy.linalg.solve(M, [1, 0, ..., 0])
cn = numpy.linalg.solve(M, [0, ..., 0, 1])
```

An example with a tri-diagonal matrix in this code:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[1,2,0],[1,4,9],[0,8,27]])
I = np.identity(3)

print(M)
#using inv
Minv1 = np.linalg.inv(M)

#using solve
Minv2 = list()
for i in range(3):
    Minv2.append(np.linalg.solve(M, I[i]))

Minv2 = np.array([list(column) for column in zip(*Minv2)])

#same as:
Minv3 = np.linalg.solve(M, I)


print(Minv1)
print(Minv2)
print(Minv3)
```

Generated output:

```
[[ 1  2  0]
 [ 1  4  9]
 [ 0  8 27]]
[[-2.          3.         -1.        ]
 [ 1.5        -1.5         0.5       ]
 [-0.44444444  0.44444444 -0.11111111]]
[[-2.          3.         -1.        ]
 [ 1.5        -1.5         0.5       ]
 [-0.44444444  0.44444444 -0.11111111]]
[[-2.          3.         -1.        ]
 [ 1.5        -1.5         0.5       ]
 [-0.44444444  0.44444444 -0.11111111]]
```

The numpy.linalg.solve function is supposed to have a higher precision than the numpy.linalg.inv.

With n=5:

```
M = np.array([[1,2,0,0,0],[1,4,9,0,0],[0,8,27,1,0],[0,0,81,1,2],[0,0,0,1,23]])
I = np.identity(len(M))

print(M)
#using inv
Minv1 = np.linalg.inv(M)

#using solve
Minv2 = list()
for i in range(len(M)):
    Minv2.append(np.linalg.solve(M, I[i]))

Minv2 = np.array([list(column) for column in zip(*Minv2)])

#same as:
Minv3 = np.linalg.solve(M, I)


print(Minv1)
print(Minv2)
print(Minv3)
```

Generated output:

```
[[ 1  2  0  0  0]
 [ 1  4  9  0  0]
 [ 0  8 27  1  0]
 [ 0  0 81  1  2]
 [ 0  0  0  1 23]]
[[ 1.63157895e+00 -6.31578947e-01 -9.21052632e-02  1.00877193e-01
  -8.77192982e-03]
 [-3.15789474e-01  3.15789474e-01  4.60526316e-02 -5.04385965e-02
   4.38596491e-03]
 [-4.09356725e-02  4.09356725e-02 -1.02339181e-02  1.12085770e-02
  -9.74658869e-04]
 [ 3.63157895e+00 -3.63157895e+00  9.07894737e-01  1.00877193e-01
  -8.77192982e-03]
 [-1.57894737e-01  1.57894737e-01 -3.94736842e-02 -4.38596491e-03
   4.38596491e-02]]
[[ 1.63157895e+00 -6.31578947e-01 -9.21052632e-02  1.00877193e-01
  -8.77192982e-03]
 [-3.15789474e-01  3.15789474e-01  4.60526316e-02 -5.04385965e-02
   4.38596491e-03]
 [-4.09356725e-02  4.09356725e-02 -1.02339181e-02  1.12085770e-02
  -9.74658869e-04]
 [ 3.63157895e+00 -3.63157895e+00  9.07894737e-01  1.00877193e-01
  -8.77192982e-03]
 [-1.57894737e-01  1.57894737e-01 -3.94736842e-02 -4.38596491e-03
   4.38596491e-02]]
[[ 1.63157895e+00 -6.31578947e-01 -9.21052632e-02  1.00877193e-01
  -8.77192982e-03]
 [-3.15789474e-01  3.15789474e-01  4.60526316e-02 -5.04385965e-02
   4.38596491e-03]
 [-4.09356725e-02  4.09356725e-02 -1.02339181e-02  1.12085770e-02
...
 [ 3.63157895e+00 -3.63157895e+00  9.07894737e-01  1.00877193e-01
  -8.77192982e-03]
 [-1.57894737e-01  1.57894737e-01 -3.94736842e-02 -4.38596491e-03
   4.38596491e-02]]
```

Comment: This won't work, the function is tri-diagonal not diagonal

Comment: I dont understand why that should matter

Comment: M*M^(-1) = I occurs also with tri-diagonal Matrix

Comment: why not using the data of the question? You could set `n=5`

Comment: @Makogan I don't see anything wrong with this approach. Looks like it's just solving `M . Minv = I` column by column, i.e. repeatedly solving `M . Minv(k) = I(k)` where `k` is a column index. There might or might not be a bug in the program, I didn't look hard enough, but the basic approach is valid and well known.

Comment: @RobertDodier You are correct, I made a big mistake.